# Getting Open, High, Low, Close for 5 min stock data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, stock

I have a DataFrame that contains stock data with the following columns:

```
            time    ticker  price
0   2020-04-02 09:30:35 EV  33.860
1   2020-04-02 09:00:00 AMG 60.430
2   2020-04-02 09:30:35 AMG 60.750
3   2020-04-02 09:00:00 BLK 455.350
4   2020-04-02 09:30:35 BLK 451.514
... ... ... ...
502596  2020-04-02 13:00:56 TLT 166.450
502597  2020-04-02 13:00:56 VXX 47.150
502598  2020-04-02 13:00:56 TSLA 529.800
502599  2020-04-02 13:00:56 BIDU 103.500
502600  2020-04-02 13:00:56 ON  12.700
```

Its stock price data for every 20 seconds for several hundred stocks. I have put the time column into datetime format.

From here, I need to separate the data into 5 minute intervals then plot the data, which I've done by using:

```
out = df.groupby("ticker")\
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index("time")\
                          .resample("5T")\
                          .first()\
                          .reset_index())\
        .reset_index(drop=True)

dffinal = out.dropna(axis=0)

def plot_tick(data, ticker):
    ts = data[data["ticker"]==ticker].reset_index(drop=True)
    ts.plot(x="time", y="price",title=ticker,figsize=(20,20),kind='line')

plot_tick(dffinal, "A")
```

The chart comes out well, but the problem is I need the high ,low, open, and close prices for each 5 minute interval for each stock. I need this in order to make a candlestick chart, which I can easily do once I have high, low,open, and close columns.

The open and close is the price at the beginning and end of the 5 minute period, respectively. The high and low column is the highest price during the interval, and lowest price during the interval, respectively.

So I'm looking for and end result like this:

```
         time          ticker   price        open close high low
0   2020-04-02 09:00:00 A   72.6700
6   2020-04-02 09:30:00 A   72.1400
7   2020-04-02 09:35:00 A   72.5400
8   2020-04-02 09:40:00 A   72.4000
9   2020-04-02 09:45:00 A   72.3338
... ... ... ...
38895   2020-04-02 12:40:00 ZUMZ    17.6000
38896   2020-04-02 12:45:00 ZUMZ    17.6300
38897   2020-04-02 12:50:00 ZUMZ    17.6000
38898   2020-04-02 12:55:00 ZUMZ    17.7400
38899   2020-04-02 13:00:00 ZUMZ    17.560
```

with the open, close,high,low filled in, obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, in the `groupby` you can do it by 'ticker' but also using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) on 'time' with a frequence of 5 minutes. In the `agg` method, you can use since pandas>0.25 [`pd.NamedAgg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) with `first` for open, `last` for close, `max` for high and `min` for low.

```
# dummy variables
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.date_range('2020-04-01 9:30:00', freq='20s', periods=50).tolist()*2, 
                   'ticker': ['ticker1']*50 + ['ticker2']*50, 
                   'price':np.random.randint(30, 50, 100)})

# groupby and agg, then reset_index
df_f = df.groupby(['ticker', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5T')])\
         .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='first'), 
              close=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='last'), 
              high=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='max'), 
              low=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='min'))\
         .reset_index()

print (df_f)
    ticker                time  open  close  high  low
0  ticker1 2020-04-01 09:30:00    42     37    49   30
1  ticker1 2020-04-01 09:35:00    44     33    49   30
2  ticker1 2020-04-01 09:40:00    47     32    49   30
3  ticker1 2020-04-01 09:45:00    30     36    36   30
4  ticker2 2020-04-01 09:30:00    38     48    48   31
5  ticker2 2020-04-01 09:35:00    30     44    45   30
6  ticker2 2020-04-01 09:40:00    45     34    48   30
7  ticker2 2020-04-01 09:45:00    32     40    46   32
```

for plotting candlestick with plotly, you can do:

```
import plotly.figure_factory

def plot_tick(data, ticker):
    ts = data[data["ticker"]==ticker].reset_index(drop=True)
    fig = plotly.figure_factory.create_candlestick(ts.open, ts.high, ts.low, 
                                                   ts.close, dates=ts.time)
    fig.show()

plot_tick(df_f, 'ticker1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked to create the right data frame but for some reason the candlestick chart is all messed up. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: @dergky not sure to follow and I never plot candlestick but the provided code to plot is not really for candlestick, it seems to do a regular line plot, so do you use any specific function to plot the candlestick?

Comment: @I'm trying to use Plotly to do it... I'm going to try with Matplotlib

Comment: @dergky with plotly it seems to work for me, see my edit

Comment: tried this in Jupyter notebook and it came out better but still funny... What IDE are you using? It doesn't work in Spyder and my Pycharm is messed up

Comment: @dergky I'm using jupyter notebook, with the dummy sample I use, the result looks ok knowing that it is the first time I'm plotting this kind of graph. maybe if you have too mny data it is not working properly?! try with another frequency like 20T to have less data points to plot?

Comment: I figured it out, some old code that was unnecessary that I forgot to take out was screwing it up lol. Thank you very much for your help!!